# Recursive Depth First Search in Javascript vs Python

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search

So I am doing algorithm problems on AlgoExpert, and I came across a recursive DFS algorithm. Originally I tried solving it in JavaScript but was having issues. When I watched the code walk-through I saw that the way it was solved is super easy.

Here is the Python solution:

```py
def depthFirstSearch(self, array):
    array.append(self.name);
    for child in self.children:
        child.depthFirstSearch(array);
    return array
```

My question is, how would you achieve the same thing in JavaScript? I tried doing:

```js
function depthFirstSearch(array) {
    array.push(this.name);
    for(let i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        depthFirstSearch(array[i]);
    };
    return array;
}
```

I keep getting an error:

> depthFirstSearch is not defined

I'm confused about why I'm getting the error in JavaScript, when I'm trying to recursively call the function within itself?

Here is the whole code snippet:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = [];
    }

    addChild(name) {
        this.children.push(new Node(name));
        return this;
    }

    depthFirstSearch(array) {
       /*
        * Step 1: Add the root node to the array
        *                   this.name is the root at the start
        * Step 2: Check that the left child node isn't null
        * Step 3: If the left child node isn't null, Add the left child node to the array
        * Step 4: If the left child node is null check the right child node
        * Step 5: If the right child node isn't null, add the right child node to the array
        * Step 6: Repeat steps 1-5 until there are no nodes left to check
        */
        array.push(this.name);
        const children = this.children;
        for(let i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
            depthFirstSearch(array[i]);
        };
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Random thought, but have you tried calling `this.depthFirstSearch(array[i])`? Because your function is defined in a class, it isn't accessible by just calling `depthFirstSearch`.

Comment: Look at the scope of your function, and then see how to refer methods of the same class

Comment: @ImranAhmed I did try using ```this.depthFirstSearch(array[i])``` and it said that array was undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

- `depthFirstSearch` is a method of the `Node` class, not a global function, so it should be called on a node instance. So for instance, if you have a node named `child` it should be called like `child.depthFirstSearch`
- As it is a method, you should not use the `function` keyword (in a `class` construct). This was correctly removed in the last code block you have in your question.
- The argument passed to `depthFirstSearch` should be an array, but you pass it `array[i]` which is a *node*. It should be just `array`, as in the Python code.
- The loop should not be over `array`, but over the *children* of the current node, i.e. over `this.children`. So you would have `i < this.children.length` in your `for` loop.

Some other remarks:

- No semi-colon is needed after a `for` loop. Adding it actually introduces a (harmless) empty statement.
- Using a `for..of` instead of a plain old `for` loop makes the code a bit shorter and also better mimics what the Python code does.

Corrected version:

```js
class Node {

    /* ... the other code ... */

    depthFirstSearch(array) {
        array.push(this.name);
        for (let child of this.children) {
            child.depthFirstSearch(array);
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I forgot about ```for...of``` loops in JS, so thanks for the refresher. Also, thanks for expanding my knowledge of JS!